# What tool in Termux can I use to move one partition on my USB drive to the start of the drive?

Tags: usb, partitions, termux

I had a problem where the TV that I needed to use to watch movies, kept recognizing the EFI partition as the only partition on the USB drive, And I couldn't get to the second partition.

I decided to delete the first partition, but then the TV didn't recognize the USB drive. I thought it might have something to do with the partition table having a missing partition at the start. I tried moving the partition with `parted`, but found that they removed the move feature and I need to try something else.

I can't install `sfdisk` on `Termux`. The only thing left I found was manually moving the partition left. **Is this the only solution?**

Edit: I managed to install `sfdisk`, but there are two answers on two different forum posts with two different uses of the `sfdisk` command. One of them uses just `sfdisk /dev/sda -N 1`, and the other one uses `echo '+100M,' | sfdisk --move-data /dev/sda -N 1`. Which one should I use?

Comment: Format the usb with partition type fat32. Should work

Comment: @44yu5h I can't. I have videos on the partition, that would take ages to download. If I could do that, I could just delete every partition and create a new partition from the empty space. But I can't do that.